# How to resize bmp image on C?

Tags: c, linux, bmp

For jpeg,gif,png I use libgd. ( not ImageMagick - it's not possible ). May I resize bmp image using simple method/library ?

Comment: maybe it would help to elaborate on why you can not use the ImageMagick library (as it clearly would be the easiest way). Are you resource contrained like in an embedded system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the libraries that deal with image resizing represent the image as a bitmap (i.e. an uncompressed array of pixels) internally. So it wouldn't be very hard to read in a bitmap image from a file and put it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use ImageMagick, the easiest way to resize a bitmap is [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).